# Is there a way to download webpage with it's content? (images, js)

Tags: c#, .net

I know I can download the source code of the webpage so I can have the HTML file, but is there a way to download the content it uses like images and js files?

Comment: sure, just download the webpage and search for valid links.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1041115/Webscraping-with-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

The html markup already contains links to all the resources that it requires. It's up to you to follow their urls and download them.

My recommendation will be to start with a library such as HtmlAgilityPack in order to retrieve the elements easily (by type - link, img and others). It uses Xpath-s, and is well maintained.

If you feel uncomfortable using xpath, you might want to try CsQuery. It's not supported anymore but it has most of the functionality it needs in its old versions. It's a port of JQuery so you can use CSS selectors with it.

Edit: If what you're asking is "is there an easy way to skip this whole process" then unfortunately, the answer is no.